# Python tar generation question

Tags: python, tar

I'm creating a [tar file](http://docs.python.org/library/tarfile.html) from a directory as such /home/user/bla/mydir/

Now I want to create a tar.gz file which starts from mydir/, not having directory list of the archieve content listing starting from /home/user/bla/mydir/.

How can this be done?

Here is my original one:

```
tar = tarfile.open("/home/user/mytar.tar.gz", "w:gz")
    tar.add("/home/user/bla/mydir/")
    tar.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `add()` method's `arcname` parameter:

```
tar.add("/home/user/bla/mydir/", arcname="mydir")
```